# Delphi custom component, can't position in Designer when dragging (custom setter for Top/Left properties)

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have written a component that paints a picture centered at X,Y. At runtime, the component is moved around with a `SetXY(X,Y: integer)` procedure.

To acheive this, I calculate what the `Left` and `Top` values should be in the paint routine and set them accordingly. And all that works just fine.

But when I try to do the initial positioning at design-time, I cannot position the component by dragging it to the desired location.

When I set either the `Left` or `Top` property via the Object Inspector, it works.

```pascal
procedure MyCustomComponent.SetTop(const Value: integer);
begin
  if Top = (Value) then
    exit;
    
  inherited Top := Value;
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    FY := Value + FBmp.Width div 2;
  Invalidate;
end;
    
procedure MyCustomComponent.SetLeft(const Value: integer);
begin
  if Left = (Value) then
    exit;
    
  inherited Left := Value;
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    FX := Value + FBmp.Width div 2;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

I suspect that when the component is dragged and dropped at design-time on the Form, it does not actually set the `Left` and `Top` public properties, but instead calls some other function that sets the private field members of the underlying control that I inherit the component from (`TGraphicControl`).

Comment: Setting Top property will call `SetBounds`. Same with left, width and height. So you probably should override only the `SetBounds` method.

Comment: Yes, overriding `SetBounds()` is the correct way to react to position/size changes. Also, DO NOT re-position/re-size the component during painting operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Both fpiette and Remy pointed out, overriding the `SetBounds` did the trick. When positioning a component in design time via dragging and dropping the component it does not individually set the public `Left` and `Top` properties. But instead makes a call to the `SetBounds` procedure.

```
procedure MyComponent.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then begin
    FX := ALeft + FBmp.Width div 2;
    FY := ATop + FBmp.Height div 2;
  end;
end;
```

### Edit:

After testing i found that for the component to be placed correctly on the form in runtime you have to also check the `csLoading` in component state.

So a more complete solution would be like this:

```
procedure MyComponent.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) or (csLoading in ComponentState ) then begin
    FX := ALeft + FBmp.Width div 2;
    FY := ATop + FBmp.Height div 2;
  end;
end;
```